# combineReducers converts Immutable Map into plain JS object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

According to my reading, this should not be a problem (redux is v3.3)? What am I doing wrong?

rootReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routeReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import { reducer as reduxAsyncConnectReducer } from 'redux-async-connect';
import myReducer from './modules/myReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  routeReducer,
  reduxAsyncConnectReducer,
  myReducer,
});
```

myReducer.js

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';

const initialState = Map({});

export default (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      // On the third run "@@INIT" the state gets converted from a Map to a plain JS object :(
      console.log('action:', action.type, 'state:', state);
      return state;
  }
};
```

output

```
action: @@redux/INIT
state: Map {size: 0, _root: undefined, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}

action: @@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION_x.5.a.b.w.u.f.k.8.3.q.b.s.5.e.e.4.5.c.d.i
state: Map {size: 0, _root: undefined, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}

action: @@INIT
state: Object {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try without using immutable map as the initial state... ie just use a standard object? There seems to be some issues/additional work for redux-async-connect to support immutable.js. See https://github.com/Rezonans/redux-async-connect/pull/45 for more details.